# C# WCF SOAP Attachment Issues

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, attachment, mime

I am trying to create a WCF service to accept messages from a older webservice. I have done a lot of searching on this issue but cannot seem to find it due to lack of keywords perhaps

I am attempting to consume the format:

```
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Id: <thexml.xml>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <HEAD_LABEL>
            <DOCUMENT docID = "1234">
                <ATTACHMENTS>
                    <ATTACHMENT href = "cid:itsme@website.com"/>
                </ATTACHMENTS>
            </DOCUMENT>
        </HEAD_LABEL>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1234.XML"
Content-Id: <cid:itsme@website.com>

<SOMEXML>
<UNIMPORTANT>GG</UNIMPORTANT>
</SOMXML>
  ----MIME_boundary--
```

I have two major issues:

1. My implementation gives me this error when attempting to consume because of my use of XmlSerializerFormat. See below, i am unsure how to use another type to have the rigid xml structure i require.

   > The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

   There is an error in XML document (8, 51) which is my 
   "ATTACHMENT href = "cid:itsme@website.com"/>"

How am i able to consume this message with WCF C#?

2. How can i replicate this in SOAPUI or postman, i cannot seem to associate the file i am attaching with the "Part" inside the ATTACHMENT attribute.

As for my implementation it is attempting to use the XmlSerializerFormat to allow me to create my format the exact same as what i am expecting. But it is the XmlSerializerFormat that is throwing the error.
ImportWebServices.cs:

```
namespace SOAPY.WebService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IImportWebService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadDoc")]
        ResponseBase ReceiveAttachment(Result xmlIN);

    }

 [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class Result
    {
        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        [XmlElement("HEAD_LABEL")]
        public HeadDoc headDoc { get; set; }
    };



    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class HeadDoc
    {
        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        [XmlElement("DOCUMENT")]
        public DocumentType document { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class DocumentType
    {
        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        [XmlElement("ATTACHMENTS")]
        public List<Attach> attachments { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class Attach
    {
        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        [XmlAttribute("href")]
        public byte[] href { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help on how I might be able to consume an attachment detailed in the way i have explained would be of great help

Comment: Are you able to browse to your WSDL, so you can load it into SOAP UI? You're on the right track with testing your service with a client. Postman is okay, but SOAP UI can generate your test client much faster.

Comment: I am able to use my WSDL in SOAPUI but when i attempt to attach a document i cannot select the cid:itseme@website.com. Then my method never catches the soap message.